# keith wood countdown always display 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-countdown

I'm trying to implement Keith Wood Countdown on a web page with this code, placed just before end body tag :

```
$(function(){                                                   
        var untilDate = new Date(2016,4,4,8,0);
        console.log(untilDate.getFullYear() + "-" + untilDate.getMonth() + "-" + untilDate.getDate());
        $("#next-departure").countdown($.countdown.regionalOptions["fr"]); 
        $("#next-departure").countdown(
            {
                until:untilDate,
                format:'yowdHMS'
            }
        );
    });
```

No errors in the console and the date is correct but... always display :
[No countdown running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT4zv.jpg)
[image]

Any idea on what i'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The countdown displays 0 because it is created with empty parameters, with the code:

```
 $("#next-departure").countdown($.countdown.regionalOptions["fr"]);
```

The following lines of code, in which you specify the proper parameters, will not recreate the countdown.

My solution is to include the file `jquery.countdown-fr.js` for the  regional settings, right after the `jquery.countdown.js` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown-fr.js"></script>
```

You can find this file here: https://github.com/kbwood/countdown/blob/master/jquery.countdown-fr.js.

Then, create the countdown with the following code:

```
$(function(){
    var untilDate = new Date(2016,4,4,8,0); 
    $("#next-departure").countdown({
        until:untilDate,
        format:'YOWDHMS'
    });
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/cu246mh2/.